# How to set languages for two jquery ui datepickers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two jquery ui datepickers in my page and I would like to apply a specific language for each one of them (let says german for one datepicker and italian for the other datepicker)

Now here is the problem: the last language file that is called apply its settings to all the datepickers (in this case, italian is applied in both inputs).
I'm using the following code, what should I change to apply a specific language to each of the datepickers? thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-de.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-it.js"></script>

$(function(){

    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['de']);
    $( "#en" ).datepicker();

    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['it']);
    $( "#it" ).datepicker();


    });
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is how you do it: <sup>[[Read Manual](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)]</sup>

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['de']); 
                      //  ^ first set a default locale
$("#en").datepicker($.datepicker.regional['en']);  
                 // ^ then different locale for different
$("#it").datepicker($.datepicker.regional['it']);
```

Comment: @Ajeeb.K.P, Both links are dead.

Answer (score 4):

you will have to include

> http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/minified/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qNJF5/2/)

Answer (score 3):

Use this code,

```
$("#en").datepicker("option", $.datepicker.regional["de"]);​
$("#it").datepicker("option", $.datepicker.regional["it"]);​
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#localization

Answer (score 0):

according to the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#localization), you can just pass the regional as an option to `datepicker()`, like so:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "" ] );
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
    $( "#locale" ).change(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option",
            $.datepicker.regional[ $( this ).val() ] );
    });
```